# Change View Controller from a background thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, avfoundation

I made a custom camera app and I used a background thread for a loop containing a delay. If the delay were in the main thread it would interrupt the `AVCaptureSession`.

I want to return to `ViewController` (home page of app) when my loop finishes.

```
    func takeAllPictures() {
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let frequency = Double(self.pictureFreq)!
            let x = UInt32(frequency)
            let totalTimes = Double(self.pictureTotalTime)! //number of pics
            var picsLeftCount = totalTimes
            
            while picsLeftCount > 0{
                sleep(x)
                self.takePicture()
                picsLeftCount = picsLeftCount - 1
            }
            self.goBackHome()
        }
    }
```

```
    func goBackHome() {
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.StoryBoard.viewController) as? ViewController
        view.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

My loop works until it is time to `goBackHome()` where I get a fatal error saying I can only execute `goBackHome()` from the main thread.

Is there a way I can execute `goBackHome()` or change view controllers from the background thread?

I've tried using external functions, but they still run in the background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running the contents of the goBackHome function in the main thread like this:

```
func goBackHome() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.StoryBoard.viewController) as? ViewController
        view.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever fix, thanks. It didn't work exactly how you wrote it only because Xcode required .self on things that were in a different file/class, but I wrote a function 'goHome' which contains the original ```goBackHome()``` code, then I called ```goHome``` from within the new ```DispatchQueue.main.async``` in the original ```goBackHome()``` function.

Comment: Your welcome, and sorry I didn't check that it works in Xcode.